# How can I connect database(MSSQL Server) with Mathematica?

Tags: databaselink, databases

Newly I started working with database(MSSQL Server 2012).

by google help, I created `Table` name as `EmployeesList` and also `Inserted`values 
into the table.

know I want to connect  database with `Mathematica`.for that I seen documentation and founded `OpenSQLConnection`function.but still not connected.

```
 databaseInstalizationLink="C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft SQL Server";  
 Needs["DatabaseLink`"];
 OpenSQLConnection[databaseInstalizationLink]
```

I seen `JDBC`function also but I didn't get it.

I tried `OpenSqlConnection[]`wizard also.like if you evaluate the below one line code we get the wizard that screenshots I posted below

```
   OpenSQLConnection[]
```

Step 1:

[image]

I click on `New` Button

Step 2:

[image]

I click on `Next` button.

Step 3:

[image]

Step 4:

[image]

here,I changed to `SystemLevel`.

Step 5:

[image]

but,I installed 2012 version .

Step 6:

[image]

Step 7:

[image]

here,I didn't add any properties because,I didn't understood.

Step 8:

[image]

Finally,I click on `Connect` button but,it shows `$Failed`.

I hope,everyone understood what my problem.

can anyone help me?

Fell free,If you want to edit my question.

Comment: @PinguinDirk I tried that too also,still not connected for more information I will modify my question.

Comment: @PinguinDirk ok..can You tell is it right,what I did in wizard.

Comment: as it is all MSSQL (no longer mysql) now, I am of no help. will delete other comments

Comment: At step 6 was the name of your database listed in the database field? If it is not you haven't established a proper connection yet. Does your database have a password and user name? Just to clarify, your database should appear on the list of databases in the database field and you should be able to select it,is this what is happening?

Comment: my database doesn't have password and username.I field specific database name in Step 6,still it's not working.

Comment: You can try this solution: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/24736/2266

Comment: Completely unrelated to the question, but on Windows you can use `Alt+PrtScr` to screenshot just the current window. That way you don't need to crop the screenshots.

Answer (score 2):

Please refer to my answer here, it FINALLY works after struggling for almost a year. I hope this works for everyone else. I'd suggest completely ignoring the connection wizard and going the code route:

[How to connect Mathematica 9 to MS SQL 2012 using Windows 7 enterprise (64-bit)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/26745/how-to-connect-mathematica-9-to-ms-sql-2012-using-windows-7-enterprise-64-bit/38711#38711)